# 500 error when access device detail page in wso2 IoT device mgt URL

Tags: wso2, device, iot

We configured ip via following doc and IoT worked.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Configuring+WSO2+IoT+Server+with+the+IP

But 500 error displayed when access device detail page in wso2 IoT device mgt URL.

[Error 500 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKVwr.jpg)

> TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-23 03:58:30,556] ERROR {handlebars-module} - 
>   An exception thrown when executing the script
>   '/app/units/cdmf.unit.device.type.android.device-view/device-view.js'.
>   {handlebars-module} TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-23 03:58:30,558] ERROR
>   {dynamic-files-renderer} -  Unexpected token: F
>   {dynamic-files-renderer} org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError:
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token: F
>   (/devicemgt/lib/modules/handlebars/handlebars-v2.0.0.js#2236(Function)#2(Function)#2)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
>     at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.parse(NativeJSON.java:112)     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.execIdCall(NativeJSON.java:88)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.app.modules.c4._c_anonymous_5(/devicemgt/app/modules/batch-provider-api.js:128)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.app.modules.c4.call(/devicemgt/app/modules/batch-provider-api.js)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.app.modules.business_controllers.c1._c_anonymous_5(/devicemgt/app/modules/business-controllers/device.js:76)    at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.app.modules.business_controllers.c1.call(/devicemgt/app/modules/business-controllers/device.js)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.app.units.cdmf.unit.device.type.android.device_view.c1._c_onRequest_1(/devicemgt/app/units/cdmf.unit.device.type.android.device-view/device-view.js:28)
>     at
>   org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.app.units.cdmf.unit.device.type.android.device_view.c1.call(/devicemgt/app/units/cdmf.unit.device.type.android.device-view/device-view.js)
>     at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
>     at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.devicemgt.lib.modules.handleb

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Make sure that you have started `/analytics/bin/wso2server.sh` and `/broker/bin/wso2.sh`.

Comment: You are right. We assumed previous emm can be run normally without DAS(analytics) support so we did not run analytics base on IoT3.0, but we were wrong. Now it work, thank you very much.

Comment: Can i ask you more questions?

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 IoT 3.1.0](http://wso2.com/iot/) is released and it has included a script to change the host name to IP. Default server comes with localhost URL configurations and an SSL certificate with localhost common name. Therefore if you need to change localhost to an IP, please run the change-ip.sh script in [WSO2 IoT 3.1.0]/scripts folder.